# CustomEditor Unity: chosing enums at once + showing array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor, inspector

I'm trying to do a thing on Unity and got caught up;

This may be a bit complex, but see if you can help me:

[What I got and what I want (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Wqt.png)

This is the script I got now

```
public class ClasseTest : MonoBehaviour{


    public enum TiposDeMissoes
    {
        TipoMatarGente,
        TipoPegarItem,
    };
        public TiposDeMissoes TiposMissoes;


    [Serializable]
    public class MatarGente
    {
        public int IDmissao;
        public GameObject[] ObjetosAtivarPraMissao;
        public GameObject[] Checkpoints;
        public GameObject[] InimigosPraMatar;
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class PegarItem
    {
        public int IDmissao;
        public GameObject[] ObjetosAtivarPraMissao;
        public GameObject[] Checkpoints;
        public GameObject[] ItemsEntregar;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Missoes
    {
        public TiposDeMissoes TiposMissoes;
        public PegarItem[] PegarItem;
        public MatarGente[] MatarGente;
    }

    public Missoes[] MissoesJogasso;

}
```

I only what to show the class PegarItem if PegarItem was chosen in the enum.

There's only PegarItem and MatarGente right now, but there will be more classes.

I did some research and find out Im supposed to use the OnInspectorGUI if I want to be that specific (if there's other way round, pls tell me)

I got 0 experience on CustomEditor so what I got so far is

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(ClasseTest))]
public class TestCustomInspector : Editor
{
    public int numMissoes;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        ClasseTest script = (ClasseTest)target;

        numMissoes = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Numero de Missoes", numMissoes);

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Editante");
        var serializedObject = new SerializedObject(target);
        var property = serializedObject.FindProperty("MissoesJogasso");
        serializedObject.Update();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property, true);
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

        for (int i = 0; i < numMissoes; i++)
        {
            script.TiposMissoes = (ClasseTest.TiposDeMissoes)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("TIPO DE MISSAO", script.TiposMissoes);

            if (script.TiposMissoes == ClasseTest.TiposDeMissoes.TipoMatarGente)
            {
                script.TiposMissoes = (ClasseTest.TiposDeMissoes)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Matar Gentes", script.TiposMissoes);
            }

            if (script.TiposMissoes == ClasseTest.TiposDeMissoes.TipoPegarItem)
            {
                script.TiposMissoes = (ClasseTest.TiposDeMissoes)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Pegar Item", script.TiposMissoes);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And that means, in the editor:

[If I change the value of one enum, all the others copy it (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TGKw.png)

And That's exactly what I do not want.
And y'all, keep in mind when the editor chooses MatarGente or PegarItem I'd like to show all those possible variables that these classes hold. That includes arrays with non-specific lengths.
And also, if there's 2 'MatarGente' I'd like to be able to fill those arrays with different objects and retrieve that information later to use it somewhere else.

Comment: If you use a lot of arrays and lists you might want to go into [ReorderableList](http://va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist/). It's a bit tricky to get into it in the beginning but once you got it it is very cool and easy to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to understand what you were doing. Your mistake was not modifying the array elements and few other issues.

This is your new `ClasseTest`:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ClasseTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TiposDeMissoes
    {
        TipoMatarGente,
        TipoPegarItem,
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MatarGente
    {
        public int IDmissao;
        public GameObject[] ObjetosAtivarPraMissao;
        public GameObject[] Checkpoints;
        public GameObject[] InimigosPraMatar;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class PegarItem
    {
        public int IDmissao;
        public GameObject[] ObjetosAtivarPraMissao;
        public GameObject[] Checkpoints;
        public GameObject[] ItemsEntregar;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Missoes
    {
        public TiposDeMissoes TiposMissoes;
        public PegarItem[] PegarItem;
        public MatarGente[] MatarGente;
    }

    public List<Missoes> MissoesJogasso;
    public int NumMissoes;
}
```

This is your new `TestCustomInspector` class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ClasseTest))]
public class TestCustomInspector : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        ClasseTest script = (ClasseTest)target;

        script.NumMissoes = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Numero de Missoes", script.NumMissoes);
        // Ensure it cannot go into negative numbers.
        if (script.NumMissoes < 0) script.NumMissoes = 0;

        // Create the list if it does not exist.
        if(script.MissoesJogasso == null) script.MissoesJogasso = new List<ClasseTest.Missoes>();

        // numMissoes being greater than the current count means we need to extend the list.
        if (script.NumMissoes > script.MissoesJogasso.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < script.NumMissoes; i++)
            {
                script.MissoesJogasso.Add(new ClasseTest.Missoes());
            }
        }
        // numMissoes being less than the current count means we need to decrease the list.
        else if(script.NumMissoes < script.MissoesJogasso.Count)
        {
            int difference = script.MissoesJogasso.Count - script.NumMissoes;

            // Remove the last element difference number of times.
            for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++)
            {
                script.MissoesJogasso.RemoveAt(script.MissoesJogasso.Count - 1);
            }
        }

        var serializedTarget = new SerializedObject(target);

        for (int i = 0; i < script.MissoesJogasso.Count; i++)
        {
            var missoes = script.MissoesJogasso[i];

            switch(missoes.TiposMissoes)
            {
                case ClasseTest.TiposDeMissoes.TipoMatarGente:
                    missoes.TiposMissoes = (ClasseTest.TiposDeMissoes)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Matar Gentes", missoes.TiposMissoes);
                    DrawProperty(serializedTarget, string.Format("MissoesJogasso.Array.data[{0}].MatarGente", i));
                    break;

                case ClasseTest.TiposDeMissoes.TipoPegarItem:
                    missoes.TiposMissoes = (ClasseTest.TiposDeMissoes)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Pegar Item", missoes.TiposMissoes);
                    DrawProperty(serializedTarget, string.Format("MissoesJogasso.Array.data[{0}].PegarItem", i));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void DrawProperty(SerializedObject serializedObject, string propertyName)
    {
        var property = serializedObject.FindProperty(propertyName);
        serializedObject.Update();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property, true);
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

In Unity:

[image: The custom inspector in Unity]

Hope this works.

Comment: Not exactly but it looks better than before. I can now change the enums values individually, so they're not longer changing each others,

Comment: But theres not a message in the console everytime I type something on the first field ("Numero de Missoes", numMissoes) that says 'Argument is out of range: Parameter name index'

Comment: @Milena I've updated the `TestCustomInspector` class, tell me if it works.

Comment: But thats anyway a huge upgrade so far thanks. I will test it.

Comment: I got like 3 more errors on that one sorry :x Ill try to work something outta the other version you sent.

Comment: @Milena Sorry about the last issues. I've tested the code in Unity and it works perfectly. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Yeah, it works just like the picture you sent me, except it shows only the enums, its not showing all the arrays I got in each class like I posted on the first picture on the question(What I got and what I want (image))

Comment: Thanks for not giving up, really <3

Comment: @Milena Took a look at the image, and it seems to be working perfectly now.

Comment: It works. Oh my god I cant actually believe you solved it out.